# Lexological String Sorting Query

Tags: java, sorting

So I am a beginner in Java and was solving from a book where the question was :

> Write a program that sets up a String variable containing a paragraph
>   of text of your choice. Extract the words from the text and sort them
>   into alphabetical order. Display the sorted list of words. You could
>   use a simple sorting method called the bubble sort. To sort an array
>   into ascending order the process is as follows: a. Starting with the
>   first element in the array, compare successive elements (0 and 1, 1
>   and 2, 2 and 3, and so on). b. If the first element of any pair is
>   greater than the second, interchange the two elements. c. Repeat the
>   process for the whole array until no interchanges are necessary. The
>   array elements are now in ascending order.

To which my solution was:

```
public class bubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Homer = "He was the son of Epikaste and Telemachus. " +
                "He was said to be a court singer ";

        String swap;
        Homer = Homer.replace(',', ' ');
        Homer = Homer.replace('.', ' ');
        Homer = Homer.replace("  ", " ");

        String[] words = Homer.split(" ");

        for(String val:words){
            System.out.println(val);
        }

        System.out.println(" ---- SORTED -------");

        boolean exchange = true;
        while (exchange) {
            exchange = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < (words.length - 1); ++i) {
                if (words[i].charAt(0) > words[i + 1].charAt(0)) {

                    swap = words[i];
                    words[i] = words[i + 1];
                    words[i + 1] = swap;
                    exchange = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for(String val:words){
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }
}
```

However the sorted output wasn't as intended !

> He was the son of Epikaste and Telemachus He was said to be a court
>   singer  ---- SORETED ------- Epikaste He He Telemachus and a be court
>   of son said singer the to was was

Where have I made a mistake? Thanks !

Comment: your output first shows words starting with uppercase then the ones in lowercase. without looking at your code I think you forgot about the different codes of uppercase and lowercase letters :)

Comment: also class names should start with uppercase letter

Comment: also, variable names should start with lowercase letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way would be to convert all words to upper or lower case.

However, the correct way to compare words of a language in Java is to use the [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)

```
Collator myCollator = Collator.getInstance(); // optional: pass your locale
if( myCollator.compare("abc", "ABC") < 0 )
    System.out.println("abc is less than ABC");
else
    System.out.println("abc is greater than or equal to ABC");
```

This makes sure that words with special characters like 'è' or 'ä' are sorted correctly. While this makes no difference for your example, if you are learning Java, learn it right from the start.

---

In your example, create a collator instance at the beginning of the method and replace

```
if (words[i].charAt(0) > words[i + 1].charAt(0))
```

with

```
if (myCollator.compare(words[i], words[i+1]) > 0)
```

Comment: Is there a way to sort the letters without changing the case?

Comment: *This* is the way to sort the words without changing the case

Comment: Thanks ! Being unfamiliar with Collator class made me as the previous question.

Answer (score 2):

It is sorted Capital letters are less than lower case letters in ascii to get the correct sorting change all the capitals to lower case or vise versa while sorting

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Is there a way to sort the letters without changing the case?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you don't like in the result is that it sorted uppercase (capitalized) words before lowercase words. This is not surprising, because uppercase characters A-Z use the code points 65 through 90, whereas lowercase chars a-z have code points 97 through 122. So uppercase chars are always "smaller" than lowercase chars in a comparision.

Solution: Convert all words to lowercase for the comparison. Use `String.toLowerCase()` for that.

For example, instead of your original code

```
for (int i = 0; i < (words.length - 1); ++i) {
    if (words[i].charAt(0) > words[i + 1].charAt(0)) {
```

do it more like

```
for (int i = 0; i < (words.length - 1); ++i) {
    String w = words[i].toLowerCase();
    String w1 = words[i+1].toLowerCase();
    if (w.charAt(0) > w1.charAt(0)) {
```

Comment: Is there a way to sort the letters without changing the case?

Comment: Sort the letters? Thought you were sorting *words*? ;-) Anyway, this does not change the case of your words, it only makes lowercase copies. (Strings are immutable in Java, you cannot change them, you can only make derivates.) The sorting still takes place in your original data.